# How can I convert a BINARY(8000) column to VARBINARY(MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an existing table with a `BINARY(8000)` column. I tried to do something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Member] 
  ALTER COLUMN [PublicCertificate] VARBINARY(MAX)
```

and I get this:

> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> Cannot create a row of size 8086 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I understand that `BINARY(8000)` always returns a length of 8000 and that + the other 3 columns is `>= 8086`. Is there some `ALTER COLUMN` way to do this? Any ways other than deleting the table and starting over? That does work, but is an un-elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: the solution should be added as an answer and marked as correct.  That way people can more easily find your solution and/or unanswered questions.  While inspired by Joe's answer, your solution is a bit different so add it as a new answer.

Comment: @Tevo - Thanks for the suggestion. I've added it as an answer and can accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the suggestions. The first one gave me the idea for the solution. This is what I did:

```
1) CREATE TABLE [MemberTemp] (
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PublicCertificate] [varbinary](max) NULL
)

2) SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MemberTemp] ON

3) INSERT INTO [MemberTemp] ( [ID], [PublicCertificate] )
     SELECT [ID], [PublicCertificate] FROM [Member]

4) ALTER TABLE [Member] DROP COLUMN [PublicCertificate]

5) ALTER TABLE [Member] ADD [PublicCertificate] VARBINARY(MAX)

6) I went to the clustered index ran Rebuild to free space...

7) UPDATE [Member] SET [PublicCertificate] = [MemberTemp].PublicCertificate
   FROM [Member]
   INNER JOIN [MemberTemp] on [Member].[ID] = [MemberTemp].ID
```

Bang! That did it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet is to create a new column, copy over the values with one big `update` statement, then delete the original column and [rename the new one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx).

If your table is small enough, it should happen very fast and not disrupt anything. If you've got a ton of rows though, it might be worth scheduling a short downtime.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. It lets me add the column but throws the same error when I try to do the update to copy the data over.

Comment: Ahhh, but that gives me an idea: I can copy the data for that one column and the ID field to another table, delete the original column and copy the data back. That should work.

Comment: Right, I wasn't thinking in terms of the particular error message you were getting - your table is already too big, so adding more columns would fail. You may want to look into shaving some bytes off of your existing columns - I'm assuming you have a lot of columns on that table, so if you can shrink any of those (reduce `bigint` to `int`, etc.) or kill off unused columns, you'd benefit from that.

Comment: @Jim or just create a new table, copy the data over, drop the old table, and rename the new one. Saves you one set of copying the whole table.